# Почему Idea подчеркивает красным цветом что не так?

Tags: java

```
public static void moveRobot(Robot robot, int toX, int toY) {
        System.out.println("Начальная позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());

        if (robot.getY() != toY) {
            while (robot.getDirection() != (robot.getY() < toY)? Direction.UP :  Direction.DOWN) {
                robot.turnLeft();
            }
            while (robot.getY() != toY) {
                robot.stepForward();
            }
        }
        if (robot.getX() != toX) {
            while (robot.getDirection() != (robot.getX() < toX)? Direction.RIGHT :  Direction.LEFT) {
                robot.turnLeft();
            }
            while (robot.getX() != toX) {
                robot.stepForward();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Ending позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разве он не пишет **что не так** ?

Comment: Если навести мышкой на ошибку, то он даже скажет в чём она заключается

Comment: Не знаю java, но у вас `Robot.getDirection()` разве возвращает логическое значение (сомневаюсь, судя по названию)? Предполагаю, что результатом `<` является логическое значение в java.

Comment: Так как без не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала выполнится действие `(robot.getY() < toY)`.
Затем Сравнивается enum (Скорее всего) с значением boolean.
`robot.getDirection() != (robot.getY() < toY)`.
И только после этого выполнение тернарного оператора.

Правильно расставленные скобки решают эту проблему

`robot.getDirection() != (robot.getY() < toY ? Direction.UP : Direction.DOWN)`

Comment: Спасибо внимательность подводит